# NSTextView refuses to scroll more than 5 pages

Tags: swift, cocoa, nstextview

I built an OS X swift 3 application that uses an NSTextview. It works great but when I try to write or paste more than 5 pages (5 full screens of the NSTextView), then the text is not visible.

I know the text is sill there because if I select all text >> copy it >> paste it to another text editor (e.g. word) then I can see the whole text I pasted and written. But for some reason the NSTextView just refuses to scroll more than 5 pages. The scroll bar looks like it reached the bottom of the document, but actually the document contains more text.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: At the end, I solved it by deleting the NSTextview and replacing it by a new one. I don't know what was the reason for this strange behavior.